# Android map show my location didn't work

Tags: android, emulation

I have been struggle the get current location in google map, I even tried the official map demo, which not working also.  It shows the getmylocation button on the upper right, but it didn't show any blue dot on the map which is my current location.
Here is my code and i'm using emulator target api 23,  i guess it may be the emulator's problem  since the code i download directly from github.
Any advice will be much appreciated. [screenshot][1]

```
    package com.example.mapdemo;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    /**
     * This demo shows how GMS Location can be used to check for changes to the users location.  The
     * "My Location" button uses GMS Location to set the blue dot representing the users location.
     * Permission for {@link android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION} is requested at run
     * time. If the permission has not been granted, the Activity is finished with an error message.
     */
    public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements
            OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
            OnMapReadyCallback,
            ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

        /**
         * Request code for location permission request.
         *
         * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
         */
        private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

        /**
         * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
         * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
         */
        private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            mMap = map;

            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
            enableMyLocation();
        }

        /**
         * Enables the My Location layer if the fine location permission has been granted.
         */
        private void enableMyLocation() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission to access the location is missing.
                PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
            } else if (mMap != null) {
                // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
            // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                return;
            }

            if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
                enableMyLocation();
            } else {
                // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
                mPermissionDenied = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResumeFragments() {
            super.onResumeFragments();
            if (mPermissionDenied) {
                // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
                showMissingPermissionError();
                mPermissionDenied = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
         */
        private void showMissingPermissionError() {
            PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                    .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }

    }

**strong text**
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDhk2.png
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a fresh image for an emulator for the first time there aren't any location coordinates saved to the device and it doesn't use your computer's location.

Click on the "More" option on the righthand sidebar, this should open the "Extended controls" window. Select the "Location" tab (it should be selected by default) and change the Latitude and Longitude inputs to your heart's desire and click "SEND". Voilà!